# Database Relationship Between Tables

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I currently have 2 database tables set up in phpmyadmin, Destinations and Airlines. The destinations table has Destination_ID, Destination_City and Destination_Country. The Airlines table has Airline_ID, Airline and Website.

I am looking for a way to link these tables so that a destination can have one or more airlines that fly there and also so that an airline can fly to one or more destinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a link table between the two if you want.

```
Airline_Destination_Link
-----------------------------------
id | airline_id | destination_id
```

And then essentially this table links to the other two tables in a query like so:

```
SELECT a.* , d.* FROM 
    AIRLINES a
JOIN
    Airline_Destination_Link adl
ON
    adl.airline_id = a.AIRLINE_ID
JOIN
    DESTINATION d
ON
    d.DESTINATION_ID = adl.destination_id
WHERE
    a.AIRLINE_ID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. However when i run the query there is 2 Airline_ID fields and 2 Destination_ID fields in the table. Is there a way i can get rid of these so there is only one of each? Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question to answer your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your table relationship should be like

```
Airline has many destinations
Destination has many airlines
```

So its a `many to many relationship` between `Airline` and `Destination`. You would need a join table to store the relationship

```
airline_destinations

1. airline_id
2. destination_id
```